# Adjust Windows Storage Allocation for Ubuntu Installation

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows-7, ubuntu-gnome

I am going to dual boot my windows 7 laptop with ubuntu. I would like to know if it's possible to allocate storage from the e drive to Ubuntu while allocating storage

Comment: Yes I apologise for not mentioning that

Comment: Simply use Windows Disk Management to shrink the size of Drive `E:` and that space will be available when you go to install Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Terms: storage (disk) versus memory (RAM, random access memory). If system fills up RAM, it will use simulated disk memory, called virtual memory or 'paging' in Windows. Linux calls that swap space. Swap is much slower than RAM. Swap can be created on any devices you have for storage. Linux does not use term like 'e' for a drive, all disk has name that begins with common root, /dev.

So, in summary, yes, if you mean memory, it is swap you want. But I suggest you get more physical RAM if you mean memory because swap space is slow.

Otherwise, you mean storage. Answer is yes. The drive can be mounted if it if formatted with a file system you OS understands. Linux usually cannot read WI dows NTFS unless you install driver packages and restart some services. Answer on how to mount the storage depends on the kind of system you are running, it may be easy in a GUI desktop. If you still have question, sharpen up your terms and ask again. Or search for 'mount disk drive'.